# Android 4.1.3 parameter hints activation/deactivation

Tags: types, activation

Im trying to find this function, used to be in:
File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance
[image]

but in newer versions (like 4.1.3) it differs

[image]

I remember that I had already activated it to show the data type but after a reinstallation of Android Studio it was deactivated and now I do not remember how it is done

Answer (score 0):

Just found how is made

`File` - `settings` - `Editor` - `inlay hints` - `Kotlin` (or java) - choose "types" then mark (or unmark) the box that says "show hints for" then mark (or unmark) your choices

[image: Android Studio 4.1.3]

Comment: Applies also for Android Studio 4.2.2